# How to optimize migrations in Django 1.8

Tags: django, django-orm

I'm using Django 1.8 and have an app with over 100 files in the migration folder. Is there a way in Django without deleting the files to "compress" or "optimise" these migrations so I don't have so many of them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you read this part from the django docs?

> Squashing migrations¶
>
> You are encouraged to make migrations freely and not worry about how
>   many you have; the migration code is optimized to deal with hundreds
>   at a time without much slowdown. However, eventually you will want to
>   move back from having several hundred migrations to just a few, and
>   that’s where squashing comes in.

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/